# Stay in place when resize, first html to php (Pictures)

Tags: php, html

So I've been working on this site for a friend and everything works fine except for a few buttons and images move around when the window is resized. How do I counter this problem?

Full window
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuuEa.png [image]
Resized
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaqCI.png [image]

```
<div id="topnav">
    <ul id="topnav li">
        <li id="charactersearch"><a href=""></a>
        </li>
        <li id="highscores"><a href=""></a>
        </li>
        <li id="forum"><a href="http://necronia.freeforums.org" target="_blank"></a>
        </li>
        <li id="facebook"><a href="http://facebook.com/Necronia" target="_blank"></a>
        </li>
        <li id="youtube"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/NecroniaNW/videos?view=0&flow=grid" target="_blank"></a>
        </li>
        <li id="guilds"><a href=""></a>
        </li>
        <li id="deaths"><a href=""></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the position for all your icons to be absolute.

```
left: 610px;
left: 690px;
left: 805px;
```

Etc. When you are resizing your windows they stay X pixels away from left.

Try to put your icons in a list

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>News</li>
        <li>Contact us</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

With a CSS like this

```
#navigation {
    position: relative;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#navigation ul li {
    margin-left:10%;
    display:inline;
}
```

EDIT: Are you setting your images through css? Your link doesn't appear to have anything inside. Can you add the image inside the link?

```
<li id="forum"><a href="http://necronia.freeforums.org" target="_blank"></a></li>
<li id="forum"><a href="http://necronia.freeforums.org" target="_blank"><image scr=""/></a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks, they're staying in place but they're not clickable any longer. I've made a similar list like I did with the lower navigation. Any idea why? Copied the html in the main post.

Comment: It worked when you had the image source in the html instead of the css. Thank you. I guess this works for the map pictures aswell? :-)

Comment: If they are separate images yes, if not consider to add image maps (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)